# Why returned temporary object has same address as of function local object?

Tags: c++

In the book "C++ complete reference", it is mentioned that "When an object is returned by a function, a temporary object is automatically
created that holds the return value. It is this object that is actually returned by the function". But when I write code and tested, the address of object inside the function and address of the temporary objected returned are coming out to be same. Is anything changed in new compilers regarding
returning objects?? If not, somebody please help me to understand why it is so. Thanks

```
class obj
{
public:
    obj()
    {
        cout<<"constructor\n";
    }
    ~obj()
    {
        cout<<"destructor\n";
    }
};


obj getObj()
{
    obj s;
    cout<<"In getObj:"<<&s<<"\n";
    return s;
}

void function(const obj &s)
{
    cout<<"address returned by getObj:"<<&s<<"\n";    
}

int main()
{
    function(getObj());
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 
    constructor
    In getObj:0x7ffcf0bdc4c7
    address returned by getObj:0x7ffcf0bdc4c7
    destructor

Comment: Keyword: return value optimization

Comment: copy constructor is what gets called to make a copy of the local object, and that is what the caller receives.

Comment: @NickyC, could you please provide me more details or any reference link for RVO which explains this behavior

Comment: Huh? You want to `let me google that for you`? C'mon.